# Is there a way to detect if an event happens elsewhere in my Unity 2D project?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am attempting to make Tetris on Unity 2D just for fun, but I can't think of a good way to detect when I've pressed the start button. I know this is a bad analogy, but for anyone who has ever used Scratch 2, the [Broadcast Block](https://en.scratch-wiki.info/wiki/Broadcast) would be perfect, as it sends a message which basically initiates a subroutine in a script of another sprite, which is exactly what I need.

I need the start button to send out basically a broadcast that any other script can pick up, kind of like a universal subroutine call. Is there anything similar to this in Unity 2D, or if not what is the next best thing? Any help appreciated.

Comment: throw a custom event to your parent.  Then the parent class can choose what to broadcast

Comment: I simply used public UnityEvent buttonPressed;

Comment: and then public void OnMouseUp()
    {
        buttonPressed.Invoke();
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you simply catch the keypress event? 
[unity doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html)

If you need somthing more complex for some reason there are lot of input manager on the store. Or you can code one yourself